# How to send strings and keys to Linux box (not commands) remotely using Java

Tags: java, linux, shell, ssh, jsch

I have a Linux box, that after connecting to remotely will prompt the user to complete 3 parameters that will log the user's session details, i.e. name, group, reason.

I have some Java that connects using the JSch library but I am not sure how to send the strings and keys (not commands) via the Session object to complete these parameters. How is this done?

Below is a segment of my script, where I am attempting to connect to the host and then execute the LS command, but of course before it can do this it will need to send the 3 user session detail parameters.

```
Properties config = App.getConfig(args);

    final PublicKeySshSession session = new PublicKeySshSession.Builder(
            config.getProperty("host"), 
            config.getProperty("username"), 
            Integer.parseInt(config.getProperty("port")), 
            config.getProperty("privateKeyPath")).logger(new JschLogger()).build();

    if (session == null) {
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    session.execute("ls");

}
```

I thought I would include this segement of the code to make it clearer what I am aiming to achieve.

Comment: PublicKeySshSession is not part of jsch, am I right, but your own class? Due to that, I don't see how your code snippet is useful. What actually would be useful is the actual output that you're getting for your ssh session asking for those details.

Comment: Yes it is my own class. I know it is only a segement of the script but I listed it to demonstrate what the script aims to achieve. I am really banging my head against the wall...

Comment: You could start with providing the log of what actually happens with the SSH session.

Comment: May I ask why you need the log? There won't be anything in there. The scripts falls over because it does not input the 3 session detail parameters. I would like to know if there is method for the session object to send the strings...

Comment: well, in the log there should be a prompt asking those 3 session detail parameters, right?

Comment: Also, helpful code would actually be something that you've tried using jsch, since that's what the question is about. There is no jsch in the code you've pasted.